# Waiting to connect to bluetoothd

Tags: debian, bluetooth

I can't invoke my `bluetoothctl` anymore. It waits for connections withouth success showing this in the terminal:

```
me@mashin:~$ bluetoothctl 
Waiting to connect to bluetoothd...
```

Any suggestion how to start the joyful debuging?

I am using Debian 9.2.

**Edit**

Output of `sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service`

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
```

Comment: Please add the output of `sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service` to the question.

Comment: Hint: To combine enable and start, do a `systemctl enable --now bluetooth`

Answer (score 27):

I had the same problem. I found a solution on [archlinux.org's forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=217451).

I had to load the kernel module `btusb`.
To test if this will solve the problem for you, run as root :

```
modprobe btusb
systemctl start bluetooth
```

then test if bluetoothctl works. If it does you can make this fix permanent by loading the module on boot. To do that on Debian add (as root) the line:

```
btusb
```

at the end of the file `/etc/modules`.

You might also want to ask systemd to enable the bluetooth service on boot, in this case execute (as root):

```
systemctl enable bluetooth
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar situation (I had already enabled and started the bluetooth service and it used to work fine; the service became dead suddenly).

Restarting the bluetooth service solved it:

```
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth.service
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution that I tried today for Arch Linux with XFCE is to basically enable the bluetooth service using

**systemctl enable bluetooth.service**.

I think this service loads the btusb module and then starts the service so you do not need to modify the configuration files.

Answer (score -1):

For the first, you need to start Bluetooth service, and then use bluetoothctl.

```
systemctl start Bluetooth
bluetoothctl
```